# ZF2 preventing multiple form submission

Tags: php, zend-framework2, captcha

Is there any way in ZF2 forms to prevent multiple form submission? I have tested `Captcha` and `CSRF` element with `isValid()` function but they don`t prevent multiple submission especially those with browser refresh button.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is a controller plugin called PRG:

POST /REDIRECT / GET PLUGIN

To quote from the offical zf2 docs:

> When a user sends a POST request (e.g. after submitting a form), their
>   browser will try to protect them from sending the POST again, breaking
>   the back button, causing browser warnings and pop-ups, and sometimes
>   reposting the form. Instead, when receiving a POST, we should store
>   the data in a session container and redirect the user to a GET
>   request.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-post-redirect-get-plugin

To expand further in my own words; when using this plugin, each time a form is submitted by POST the POST variables are stored to a SESSION and the user is redirected, either to a different route or simply the same route (refresh). The Form variables are then accessible via the PRG plugin as a simple array mimicking the original POST array. This will prevent the FORM being posted multiple times.

Usage (from ZF2 docs):

```
// Pass in the route/url you want to redirect to after the POST
$prg = $this->prg('/user/register', true);

if ($prg instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response) {
    // returned a response to redirect us
    return $prg;
} elseif ($prg === false) {
    // this wasn't a POST request, but there were no params in the flash messenger
    // probably this is the first time the form was loaded
    return array('form' => $myForm);
}

// $prg is an array containing the POST params from the previous request
$form->setData($prg);

// ... your form processing code here
```

Comment: Thanks man.I will test it and give you the results. By the way, why ZF2 captcha is not totally one-time-use?

Comment: you can find more specific info about CAPTCHA within a ZF2 form here: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.form.elements.html#captcha

Comment: I have read all those docs and didnt find anything related to my issue. I tested what you said. It is a great plugin but didnt solve the problem completely. The refresh button is solved because there was no other info to resend via browser. But if you send those info via a hack tool like fiddler or burp suite, you will see that the captcha is still valid. This can let hackers easily bypass our captchas.

Comment: I was specifically answering your question 'how to prevent multiple form submissions in ZF2'. 

The troubles you are having configuring captcha probably warrants a new question being posted with examples of your code, etc.

Comment: After all that was a great plugin and thank you for that.I did create another questions. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26864537/zf2-captcha-security-issue) and [here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/6857)

Comment: Your captcha question has been answered at the zf site you linked to above.